# Как вынести создание формы в отдельный класс?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как правильно вынести создание формы в отдельный класс и нормально к ней обращаться?

```
public void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = new Form();
    form.Show();

    form.Controls.Add(listBox1);
    listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
    listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Title";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "Path";
    listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
    listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
   
    butReset.Text = "Сбросить настройки";
    butReset.Location = new Point(140, 160);
    form.Controls.Add(butReset);

    butLoad.Text = "Принять";
    butLoad.Location = new Point(30, 160);
}
```

Сейчас на кнопке висит много кода (Создание формы в том числе). Смысл в том, что этот код нужно использовать во множестве разных мест. Мне бы хотелось иметь возможность быстро интегрировать код создания формы в другие проекты и иметь возможность масштабирования сего кода. Сейчас выглядит ужасно (на мой взгляд) , но как его вынести я не знаю.

Comment: Ух, какой-то прям нечастый вопрос на ru so - "как сделать правильно", не пожалею плюса. А поясните всё же, что такое "правильно" по-вашему, какие сценарии использования или от чего вы вообще хотите уйти в своём коде?

Comment: @ebw1910 вынесите тот код, который вы хотите расшарить между проектами в отдельный метод в отдельный класс. и шарьте его. "как правильно" - понятие субъективное

Comment: Я же вам написал в Code Review [что сделать](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/262741/226545) - вы не заметили комментарий?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вариант так

```
public void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form form = new MyCustomForm();
    form.Show();

}
```

у вас заготовленная форма и вы её создаёте.

или другой вариант.

Если форма предполагает создание динамически то рекомендую создать фабрику. Которая и будет генерировать вам формы

```
class FormFactory {

   public static Form createForm(yourParams) {
    // создаёте форму на основе параметров 
    Form form = new Form();
   
    form.Controls.Add(listBox1);
    listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
    listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Title";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "Path";
    listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
    listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
   
    butReset.Text = "Сбросить настройки";
    butReset.Location = new Point(140, 160);
    form.Controls.Add(butReset);

    butLoad.Text = "Принять";
    butLoad.Location = new Point(30, 160);

    return form;

   }

}



public void LoadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // подготавливаете параметры формы 
    ....
    Form form = FormFactory.createForm(yourParams);

    form.Show();    
}
```

Comment: А жмякнуть в солюшн эксплорере Добавить -> Форма - не спортивно? :)

Comment: @aepot ну я и привел пару идей. А руками создавать или нет дело хозяйское. Кому подойдет кому нет. Спорт тоже в жизни не всегда применишь :)) спс за +

Comment: @aepot он вроде про жмякнуть в начале сказал `new MyCustomForm()`